# What does 'set the RESUME variable to override this' after sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall mean?

Tags: apt, nvidia, kernel

My Windows 10, Ubuntu 18 dual boot Ubuntu kept shutting down so I looked online and learned that I should reinstall nvidia drivers so I did a `purge` and then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

At the tail end of the installation, I got the messages below:

```
DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-driver-390 (390.129-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-60-generic
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=21b1e4a0-29c2-4f93-8745-90d231ee3a96
W: but no matching swap device is available.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda6
I: (UUID=8f292314-3eb2-421f-b1bc-02f9583f552f)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I saw some complex answer on making changes to some system files but as I have seriously messed up my Ubuntu installations before following advice I did not fully understand, am asking here for clarification on what the message means, what if anything I should do and where I can learn more about the problems and fixes.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pilot6 the question is edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that UUID of your swap partition or file has changed.

If this was a partition, you can check it's UUID by `sudo blkid` and add the correct one to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

It is important only if you are using hibernation.

Comment: I always use hibernation.  Thanks for sma.

Answer (score 6):

This error means that UUID of your swap partition or file has changed!

For a SWAP Partition vs a SWAP File (Not Recommended)

You can check it's UUID by:

`sudo blkid`,     and  mine was

> /dev/sda2: UUID="139d357c-829d-408d-bccc-147ec4402da8" TYPE="swap"
>   PARTLABEL="HDD_Swap" PARTUUID="0067903b-aed0-48d1-8d59-956784616d48""

Add this line to (and likely an empty file):

> RESUME=UUID=139d357c-829d-408d-bccc-147ec4402da8

To this file:

> /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

Using this command should you choose it.

```
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

∘ Important ... it is very COUNTER INTUITIVE! but set it to the DISCs UUID not the Partitions PARTUUID, and in my case it WAS the one In the error - ODD Message!)

Then reboot or just update what's necesswary with this command:

> sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

I hope it helps, mark